# Search and replace text in PDF using JAVA

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

Need to replace the text in the pdf with different language. In the first step, I was trying to search and replace a text in the pdf file using itextpdf ad pdfbox API.

Use the below code snippet which uses itextpdf api to search and replace the text "Hello" to "Hi" from the source PDF file. The new PDF is created without any text replacements.

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
    int noOfPages = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 1; i < noOfPages; i++) {
        PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(i);
        PdfDictionary dict = page.getPdfObject();
        PdfObject object = dict.get(PdfName.Contents);
        if (object instanceof PdfStream) {
            PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) object;
            byte[] data = stream.getBytes();
            stream.setData(new String(data).replace("Hello", "Hi").getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
    }
    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

Also used apache pdfbox to achieve the same thing but no luck in that. Below is the code snippet for the reference.

```
    public static PDDocument replaceText(PDDocument document, String searchString, String replacement)
        throws IOException {        
    for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
        parser.parse();
        List tokens = parser.getTokens();
        for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
            Object next = tokens.get(j);
            if (next instanceof Operator) {
                Operator op = (Operator) next;
                // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display strings in a PDF
                if (op.getName().equals("Tj")) {
                    // Tj takes one operator and that is the string to display
                    // so lets update that operator
                    COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    String string = previous.getString();
                    //System.out.println(new String(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    string = string.replaceFirst(searchString, replacement);
                    previous.setValue(string.getBytes());

                } else if (op.getName().equals("TJ")) {
                    COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                    for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                        Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                        if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                            COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                            String string = cosString.getString();
                            //System.out.println("22::"+new String(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                            string = StringUtils.replaceOnce(string, searchString, replacement);
                            cosString.setValue(string.getBytes());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(document);
        OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
        ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
        tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
         // save content
        page.setContents(updatedStream);
        out.close();
    }
```

Any solution/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: could you attach source pdf?

Answer (score 4):

This is a working version, uses PDFBox

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.Operator;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSString;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.ContentStreamWriter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;

public final class PDFEditor {

    private PDFEditor() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = null;
        document = PDDocument.load(new File("src path"));
        document = replaceText(document, "Hello", "Hi");
        document.save("target Path");
        document.close();
    }

    private static PDDocument replaceText(PDDocument document, String searchString, String replacement) throws IOException {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(searchString) || StringUtils.isEmpty(replacement)) {
            return document;
        }

        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
            parser.parse();
            List<?> tokens = parser.getTokens();

            for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
                Object next = tokens.get(j);
                if (next instanceof Operator) {
                    Operator op = (Operator) next;

                    String pstring = "";
                    int prej = 0;

                    if (op.getName().equals("Tj")) {
                        COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                        String string = previous.getString();
                        string = string.replaceFirst(searchString, replacement);
                        previous.setValue(string.getBytes());
                    } else if (op.getName().equals("TJ")) {
                        COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                        for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                            Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                            if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                                COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                                String string = cosString.getString();

                                if (j == prej) {
                                    pstring += string;
                                } else {
                                    prej = j;
                                    pstring = string;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (searchString.equals(pstring.trim())) {
                            COSString cosString2 = (COSString) previous.getObject(0);
                            cosString2.setValue(replacement.getBytes());

                            int total = previous.size() - 1;
                            for (int k = total; k > 0; k--) {
                                previous.remove(k);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(document);
            OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
            ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
            tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
            out.close();
            page.setContents(updatedStream);
        }

        return document;
    }

}
```

Dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.11</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried the code which you have suggested still this is not working. Is this working on your end?

Comment: Yes, it's working. Can you post your main method as well.

Comment: i have the source pdf file.. but in stackoverflow there is no option to attach it here

Comment: I ran the file as it is i.e.PDFEditor which you have created

Comment: can you upload your document somewhere on cloud and share link , if not confidential.

Comment: Please get the file attached in this location https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E3GXycaAU5xT2ca4D48oEaOGnp5Qx4Ra/view

Comment: I haven't looked at the PDF but read this: Why was the ReplaceText example removed? https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed

Comment: Well good luck with replacement: "Hello Jack" is "[ (H) -3 (e) 4 (llo ) -3 (J) 6 (ack) -3 (,) ] TJ".

Comment: As explained in the page referenced by @Tilman, code like the `PDFEditor` only works with very specific documents. Just like the itext code the op stated with in his question.

Comment: Any idea how to replace the text as  the above code is meant for specific pdf

Comment: @user3751824 use regular expressions, like "[H].*?[E].*?[L].*?[L].*?[O]"

Answer (score -2):

please use  Below  Working , with  using any

`

```
package com.pdf;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class ItextTestMain {


    public static final String SRC = "C:\\JavaApp\\Pdf\\input\\inputFile.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "C:\\JavaApp\\Pdf\\output\\outPutFile"+new Date().getTime() +".pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        processPDF(SRC, DEST);
    }

    public static void processPDF(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        int pNumbers = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PRStream stream;
        for (int i= 1 ; i <= pNumbers;i++){
            PdfDictionary  dict = reader.getPageN(i);
            PdfObject  object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
            if (object instanceof PRStream) {
                  stream = (PRStream) object;
                byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
                String dd = new String(data);
                dd = dd.replaceAll("old_text", "old_text");
                stream.setData(dd.getBytes());
            }
        }

        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }

}

------------------------------------------------

Maven dependencies to add  POM.xml

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6</version>
</dependency>`
```