# Masking aadhaar number in an UIDAI aadhaar pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

Does anybody know how to mask aadhaar number in an aadhaar pdf downloaded from UIDAI website.

I have already tried below code for itext. It is not working for an aadhaar PDF but is working for other normal pdfs

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new MainClassName().manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
}

public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary dict = reader.getPageN(1);
    PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    PdfArray refs = null;
    if (dict.get(PdfName.CONTENTS).isArray()) {
        refs = dict.getAsArray(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    } else if (dict.get(PdfName.CONTENTS).isIndirect()) {
        refs = new PdfArray(dict.get(PdfName.CONTENTS));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < refs.getArrayList().size(); i++) {
        PRStream stream = (PRStream) refs.getDirectObject(i);
        byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
        stream.setData(new String(data).replace("8989 7890 4567", "XXXX XXXX 4567").getBytes());
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Tried suggestions from this post too (i.e, using pdfbox)
[Search and replace text in PDF using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027733/search-and-replace-text-in-pdf-using-java)

Even that is not working for an aadhaar PDF but is working for a normal pdf

(I know we can download a masked aadhaar pdf from UIDAI website itself, but I need to do it through JAVA)

Comment: As mentioned in a comment to the answer you referred to, code like that only works with very specific documents. The text you want to replace may be contained piece-wise as arguments of different instructions, it doesn't even need to be in reading order, and the encoding does not need to be ASCII-like.

Comment: see https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed%3F Look into the page content stream of your PDF with PDFDebugger or RUPS. (Or is the number in a form field?)

Answer (score 1):

you can convert your PDF to an Image then with help of Google Cloud OCR
and then mask text and convert it back to PDF.

**Here is Sample Project in javascript.**

https://github.com/rinkeshjain/aadhaar-mask

Comment: That's detrimental to the PDF quality.